# Pointers, linked list and function

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list, pass-by-reference

this is my first question here! 
I work with linked list and functions.

I have created this function that copies values from a structure (Passenger) to a linked list LIST1.

```
typedef struct
    {
    char fillname[40]
    }PASSENGERS;


typedef struct list1
    {
    char fullname[40];
    struct list1 *next;
    }LIST1;



   //COPYLIST

 copylist(LIST1 *list1, PASSENGERS *passenger)
    {

    LIST1 *start=NULL;
    for (i=0;i<40;i++)
        {
        list1 = (LIST1 *) malloc (sizeof(LIST1));
        list1->next = NULL;
        strcpy(list1->fullname,passenger[i].fullname);

        if (start ==NULL)
            start = list1;
        else //add new node at the beginning of list
            {
            list1->next = start;
            start = list1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside Main i call the function with the following statement

```
int main ()
PASSENGERS *passenger; 
int h;

LIST1 *list1;
list1=copylist(list1,passenger);
```

However i get nothing when printing it with :

```
LIST1 *current = list1;


    while (current !=NULL)
        {
        printf("%s",current->fullname);
        current = current->next;
```

If i don't use a function and move the code inside main everything works fine, so probably it's a problem with pointers, that i am still trying to get used of! 
Thank you

Comment: you did not return anything from copylist() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your copylist function like that :-

```
  LIST1 *copylist(LIST1 *list1, PASSENGERS *passenger)
    {

        LIST1 *start=NULL;
        int i=0;
        for (i=0;i<40;i++)
            {
            list1 = (LIST1 *) malloc (sizeof(LIST1));
            list1->next = NULL;
            strcpy(list1->fullname,passenger[i].fullname);

            if (start ==NULL)
                start = list1;
            else //add new node at the beginning of list
                {
                list1->next = start;
                start = list1;
                }
            }
            return start;
    }
```